# JPA: How do I load an entity with a Foreign Key without loading the related entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities :

```
@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    private int id;

    // login, name, email, status...
}


@Entity
public class Credential {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private Account account;

    // password, password last set, error count...
}
```

The idea behind this design is that the business code should never know about the Credential entities, only the Account entities.
Besides, we may store the credentials elsewhere (off-database), so I don't want a Credential reference inside Account.

The drawback of this design is that upon login, the Account is retrieved and checked first (not locked or disabled). Only after that do I retrieve the Credential. However, JPA then loads a second Account object to fill the foreign key.

Is there a way to prevent that ? Maybe a JPA way to give it the Account I already have and let it return the Credential ?

I could replace the foreign key 'account' in Credential with an 'accountId' that would map to the account's id, but it looks far from ideal.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your application design but you could either make `Credential.account` lazy loaded with `FetchType.LAZY`...

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId
private Account account;
```

...or alternatively you could `merge()` the account object into the persistent session so that the entity manager doesn't need to load the association, remembering of course that from then on it will be managed and all changes will be persisted. Depending on your application JPA may try to `refresh()` it though and do the SELECT anyway, I'm not certain. Write an integration test for that one!

Comment: The problem with lazy fetching is that it doesn't guarantee the account object will never be fetch. I will look to the `merge()` solution.